# The succeeding combo box didn't load the changes i made

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I have a code it will populate the combo box from mysql database. The combo box will show all the organization that has a status = 'YES'. But if i change the status from NO to YES the succeeding combo box doesn't load it.

Here's my code for the combo box:

```
string sql = "SELECT orgAbbrev FROM courseandorg WHERE status = 'YES'";
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

              while (rd.Read())
            {

                cboOrg.Items.Add(rd["orgAbbrev"].ToString());
                cboOrg.ValueMember = rd["orgAbbrev"].ToString();
                cboOrg.DisplayMember = rd["orgAbbrev"].ToString();

            }
            conn.Close();
```

Here's the code for the button where I will change the status:

```
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql1 = "UPDATE courseandorg SET status = @status WHERE connID = @connID";
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sql1, conn);

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@connID", textBox1.Text);   
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", comboBox1.Text);

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Showlist();  //This is my funtion in  my datagridview

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code this way

**section one**

```
private void your_func()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT orgAbbrev FROM courseandorg WHERE status = 'YES'";
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
        {

            cboOrg.Items.Add(rd["orgAbbrev"].ToString());
            cboOrg.ValueMember = rd["orgAbbrev"].ToString();
            cboOrg.DisplayMember = rd["orgAbbrev"].ToString();

        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

**section two**

```
        try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql1 = "UPDATE courseandorg SET status = @status WHERE connID = @connID";
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sql1, conn);

        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@connID", textBox1.Text);   
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", comboBox1.Text);

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Showlist();  //This is my funtion in  my datagridview
        your_func(); //This is new change
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```